# phpstorm Deployment обрезает файл

Tags: phpstorm, развертывание

Столкнулся с проблемой.
При деплое через phpstorm - файлы до сервера часто долетают обрезанные.
Иногда не хватает только конца файла, иногда обрезает до середины. Повторный деплой проблему не решает, приходится ручками на ftp лезть. 
Кто сталкивался - как решили проблему?

Comment: Мне кажется, видел такое пару раз, при временных проблемах связи с сервером. Обычно deployment работает как часы. Если у вас такое постоянно - меняйте хостера или локального провайдера.

Answer (score 1):

Вчера решил эту проблему. Нужно использовать в настройка deployment тип протокола 
 FTPS.
Мне это помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён.
Данная проблема возникает только если в настройках деплоя, в разделе дополнительных настроек установлен "Passive mode" 
[image: Passive mode]